# Create Ordered List Based on Div Classes

Tags: javascript

I have several `div`s that are all siblings and I would like to turn these into a outline that looks like the following:

1. One
2. Two
3. Three

   1. One

      1. One
      2. Two
   2. Two
4. Four
5. Five

I'm not quite sure how to do this. I've had some luck with the following [Codepen](https://codepen.io/fatguylaughing/pen/dzZpPV). I'm currently using CSS classes of one through ten to signify how deep we need to indent into the list.

I would like to accomplish this using Javascript.

Comment: If you are voting down the question please let me know as to why. This way I can fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a stack ... (sorry for using coffee  but the logic matters)

```
    entryLevel = [
      "one",
      "two",
      "three",
      "four",
      "five",
      "six",
      "seven",
      "eight",
      "nine",
      "ten"
    ]

    #make a class list a bit tricky 
    all_items="."+entryLevel.join(", .") 


    #this is to find the index / level of each element (could have more than on class)
    get_index = ($$) =>
      for cla, i in entryLevel
        return i+1 if $$.hasClass(cla)
```

here we go base element is `body` (or what ever you want) and we need to remember some things

```
    stack=[$('body')]
    old_index=1
    list_index=1
```

we iterate over all classes and get the index

```
    $(all_items).each (i,item) =>
        $$=$(item)
        i=get_index($$)
```

we have to remove the topmost container if we go a level back - but any how we remember the old index (here I missed the "()" after `pop`

```
        stack.pop() if i<old_index
        old_index=i
```

lets take a look if we have a list for this container, if not append a new list to parent  ...

```
        unless stack[i]
            id="list_#{list_index}"
            list_index+=1
            stack[i-1].append("<ol id='#{id}'></ol>")
            stack[i]=$("#"+id)
```

finally move the item in topmost list

```
        stack[i].append($$)
```

or as list:

```
        $$.wrap("<li></li>")
        stack[i].append($$.parent())
```

[pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EvQwqR)

Comment: Is there a way to have the divs in <li> tags?

Comment: @FatGuyLaughing, just a small error, ok now. what about using "<li id='#{id}'></lil>"?

Comment: you mean - ah - make <li> instad of <div>?

Comment: I was wondering if the HTML could easily be updated to look like <ol><li><div> that way things like screen readers, google, etc can tell that it is a list.

Comment: just "$$.wrap("<li></li>")"

Comment: When I converted this to JS using js2.coffee I am getting some funky results. I don't know enough to convert this. Is this something that is able to be done?

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to accomplish that would be to use the `margin` property.  Here is a working example using `li` elements with different `margin-left` settings.  Of course, you can change the margin values to whatever you want.

```css
.lv1,
.lv2,
.lv3 {
  list-style-type: decimal;
}

.lv2 {
  margin-left: 8px;
}

.lv3 {
  margin-left: 16px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li class="lv1">One</li>
  <li class="lv1">Two</li>
  <li class="lv1">Three
    <ol>
      <li class="lv2">One
        <ol>
          <li class="lv3">One</li>
          <li class="lv3">Two</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li class="lv2">Two</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li class="lv1">Four</li>
  <li class="lv1">Five</li>
</ol>
```

**EDIT:** Updated to reset numbering for indented items.

Comment: When the indentation starts it should be numbered back to 1. The only way I know how to do this is starting a new <ol>.

Comment: The biggest problem is, I don't have control of the HTML so I'm need to leverage Javascript in order to do this.

Comment: What is the HTML structure you have to work with? Are they `li`s or `div`s?

Comment: A JavaScript solution shouldn't be a problem; just need to know what you're starting with for HTML.

Comment: I forgot I made changes to the code pen testing something. Now it is back to normal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152268/discussion-between-freginold-and-fatguylaughing).